# Optionally use a local npm package in development environment

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using an npm package that is shared across multiple services. We are in the early stages of development right now so there are a lot of changes. It's really annoying to have to publish changes to the package and then rebuild my project every time I make a change to this package. Is there a good way to just use the local package when NODE_ENV=development otherwise use the package in the npm repository? Thanks.

edit: also it would be great to be able to test my changes locally before publishing.

Comment: I would recommend npm link here, but cannot come up with a solution to switch this in development mode. Maybe a pre/post npm script that creates/removes the npm link? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: Personally, I'd fork the dependency to create your local version and give it a different name (e.g. existing-name-DEV). Then do your NODE_ENV check in code. You could actually wrap this whole thing in it's own file to reduce the times you'd do this:

file: wrap.js
module.exports = (NODE_ENV === development) ? require('existing-name-DEV') : require('existing-name');

other files:
const existingName = require('./wrap.js');

I'd recommend cleaning up before release.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I was looking into link yesterday and that might be helpful. The other issue is that I'm using docker and git submodule - so it's not trivial to use absolute/relative paths to import stuff.

Comment: I would also recommend to look into that monorepo stuff, extremely helpful when dealing with dependencies in development: https://lernajs.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was sort of hacky but it works for now. What I do is use lerna to create symlinks for my npm package. I have a non standard lerna.json file - i.e. I'm not using a /packages folder. After that, I use a script similar to the npm package absolutize-links. This converts the symlinks created with lerna to absolute paths. Then I set up some volumes with docker compose that point to my package. It's a bit of a complicated set up but I think it is working for now. I have nodemon running to ignore all of node_modules EXCEPT for my linked package. So when I make changes in my local filesystem to the package, the nodemon running in my container will restart. \o/